# JS code that shuffles images makes the website stops responding

Tags: javascript

I have made a js code that shuffles some images of projects and I made it not to show the same project on more than one box at a time ( you have a list of images that you want to show, but they should appear randomly, and once one has been shown it can't be repeated or shown again until it disappears from the first box, I think this is a better explanation). it works but the problem is that the website stops working after some seconds. in the beginning, I declared the *randomproject* and the *projectCheck* variables in the global scope. this didn't crash the website but it showed the same project in many boxes at the same time. ( I am still a beginner in js so the code isn't good)

```
<div class="project-viewer">
                <div id="project1"></div>
                <div id="project2"></div>
                <div id="project3"></div>
                <div id="project4"></div>
                <div id="project5"></div>
                <div id="project6"></div>
            </div>
```

```
/*projects grid*/
var projects = [
    'images/project0.png',
    'images/project1.jpg',
    'images/project2.jpg',
    'images/project3.jpg',
    'images/project4.png',
    'images/project5.png',
    'images/project6.png',
    'images/project7.png',
    'images/project8.png',
    'images/project9.jpg',
    'images/project10.jpg',
    'images/project11.jpg'
],

    projectsCheck = [
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false
    ],

    project1 = document.getElementById('project1'),
    project2 = document.getElementById('project2'),
    project3 = document.getElementById('project3'),
    project4 = document.getElementById('project4'),
    project5 = document.getElementById('project5'),
    project6 = document.getElementById('project6');


function shuffle(project, projectsCheck, projects, ms) {
    'use strict';

    setInterval(function () {

        var randomproject = 0,
            oldproject = 0;
        oldproject = randomproject;
        projectsCheck[randomproject] = false;

        while (projectsCheck[randomproject] == true || randomproject == oldproject) {
            randomproject = Math.floor(Math.random() * projects.length);
        }
        projectsCheck[randomproject] = true;
        project.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + projects[randomproject] + ")";

    }
        , ms);
}

shuffle(project1, projectsCheck, projects, 11000);
shuffle(project2, projectsCheck, projects, 9000);
shuffle(project3, projectsCheck, projects, 12000);
shuffle(project4, projectsCheck, projects, 10000);
shuffle(project5, projectsCheck, projects, 8000);
shuffle(project6, projectsCheck, projects, 13000);
```

Comment: Is this right - you have a list of images that you want to show, but they should appear randomly, and once one has been shown it can't be shown again until the loop starts again?

Comment: yep, that's it. also if an image is shown in one of the boxes, it can't be shown in another until it disappears from the first box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but when I declared the *randomproject* and the *projectCheck* variables in the **shuffle** function (the parent function) it worked. anyone knows the reason?